# Why numpy arrays are slower than lists with for loops?

Tags: python, numpy

Aren't arrays supposed to be faster since they consume less memory
and as I know with arrays python doesn't apply type method on the elements as it in the lists.

```
import numpy as np
import time


length = 150000000

my_list = range(length)


list_start_time = time.time()


for item in my_list:
    pass

print(f'my_list finished in: {time.time() - list_start_time}')
# # Output => my_list finished in: 3.57804799079895

my_array = np.arange(length)

array_start_time = time.time()


for item in my_array:
    pass

print(f'my_array finished in: {time.time() - array_start_time}')
# # Output => my_array finished in: 11.598113536834717
```

Comment: They are faster if you use vectorized (read Numpy) functions. Using regular loops requires multiple switches between C libraries and the Python runtime. In short, if you use regular loops, do not use Numpy arrays. If you can use only Numpy functions, they are much faster.

Comment: Aha got it, is there a numpy function that correspond to for loop ??

Comment: No, that's the point of "vectorized". What are you actually trying to do? Multiply vectors? Simply `*` will work. Add them? same... and so forth.

Comment: I was trying to add them and I can see that it's much faster now, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.arrays are much faster when using vectorized functions or to say it another way, specifically when you are not iterating over the elements.

Here is an example.  We will add 1 to each number in the ordered list you created.

The setup is similar except I use lists instead of ranges so I can operate on the values.

```
length = 150000000
my_list = list(range(length))
my_array = np.array(my_list)
```

Using the %%timeit magic function in jupyter notebooks

```
%%timeit
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] += 1
```

gives

```
38.6 s ± 3.71 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

thats about 38 seconds per loop

On the other hand

```
%%timeit
new_array = my_array + 1
```

gives

```
772 ms ± 58.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The operation on the numpy array took under one second (~772ms) per loop while iterating through the list and adding one to each element too around 36 seconds per loop.

Comment: Thank you just a note you don't need range(len(my_list)) just my_list

Comment: timeit iterates over the list 7 times adding 1 to each value on each pass.  Using for i in my_list would work on the first iteration, but on subsequent iterations the index would be off giving "list index out of range"

Answer (score 3):

`my_list = range(length)` is a `range` object, more of a generator than a list

In the loop:

```
 for i in range(10):
      pass
```

there's no significant memory use.  But even if we did iterate on a list, each `i` would just be a reference to an item in the list.  In effect a simple pointer. The list has a data buffer, which contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.  Iteration simply requires fetching those pointers, without any object creation or processing.

In `arr = np.arange(10)`, `arr` is an array object with a datebuffer containing bytes representing the values of the integers, 8 bytes per item (in the default dtype).

```
 for i in arr:
      pass
```

`numpy` indexes each element, fetching the relevant 8 bytes (relatively fast), and converting them to a number.  The whole process is more involved than simply fetching a reference from a list's data buffer.  This process is sometimes called 'unboxing'.

To illustrate, make alist and array from that list:

```
In [4]: alist = list(range(1000))
In [5]: arr = np.array(alist)
```

Indexing the list returns a python `int` object; from the array we get a `numpy` object:

```
In [6]: type(alist[0])
Out[6]: int
In [7]: type(arr[0])
Out[7]: numpy.int64
```

Some timings:

```
In [8]: timeit [i for i in alist]
27.9 µs ± 889 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [9]: timeit [i for i in arr]
124 µs ± 625 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

iteration on the list is much faster (as you note); and based on the following timing it looks like the array iteration effectively does `[i for i in list(arr)]`:

```
In [10]: timeit list(arr)
98 µs ± 661 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The `tolist` method converts the array to a list, all the way down (to native elements), and is much faster.  `[i for i in arr.tolist()]` will actually save time.

```
In [11]: timeit arr.tolist()
22.8 µs ± 28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Another way to illustrate the 'unboxing' is to look at the `id` of the same element (taking care to avoid memory reuse):

```
In [13]: x, y = alist[10], alist[10]; id(x), id(y)
Out[13]: (10914784, 10914784)
In [14]: x, y = arr[10], arr[10]; id(x), id(y)
Out[14]: (140147220887808, 140147220887832)
```

Each time we index a list element, we get the same `id`, the same object.

Each time we index an array element, we get a new object.  That object creation takes time.

`numpy` arrays are faster -  if we do the iteration is compiled `c` code.

For example to add 100 to each element of the array or list:

```
In [17]: timeit arr + 100
3.46 µs ± 136 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [18]: timeit [i+100 for i in alist]
60.1 µs ± 125 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```