# Multiple elements of numpy array has same id

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

I am trying to understand why elements with different value have the same **id**. Could someone explain me what is going with respect to memory management in NumPy. Example  below

```py
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,3,4])
print([id(a) for a in x])
```

```py
[140718968034552, 140719258631960, 140718968034552, 140719258631960]
```

Here, first and the third element has the same **id**(140718968034552) though they hold different numerical values. Same as for second and fourth elements.

Comment: Don't pay attention to these `id` values. They aren't meaningful. Read my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63873120/901925 esp. `[14]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the id( ) function used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-is-the-id-function-used-for)

Comment: @Marios. How is that even remotely related to the question?

Comment: @Hpaulj, read the link. I understand -5 to 256 integers get static id due to memory optimization. But My question is, first and third integer objects are different (as holding different value), then why they have same id.

Comment: Look at the `type` of `a`.  It isn't `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [54]: x=np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [55]: [type(a) for a in x]
Out[55]: [numpy.int64, numpy.int64, numpy.int64, numpy.int64]
In [56]: [id(a) for a in x]
Out[56]: [140147220886728, 140147220887808, 140147220886728, 140147220887808]
```

The id of small integers is unique, but that's not what the array contains:

```
In [57]: [type(a) for a in x.tolist()]
Out[57]: [int, int, int, int]
In [58]: [id(a) for a in x.tolist()]
Out[58]: [10914496, 10914528, 10914560, 10914592]
In [59]: id(2)
Out[59]: 10914528
```

Another way to get the `int` objects:

```
In [60]: [id(a.item()) for a in x]
Out[60]: [10914496, 10914528, 10914560, 10914592]
```

### edit

If I assign the elements of `x` to a tuple of variables, the `id` are not reused.  `id(x0)` is still in use, so `id(x2)` cannot take it.  The alteration in `Out[56]` is just an artifact of memory reuse by the interpreter.

```
In [73]: x0,x1,x2,x3 = x
In [74]: id(x0),id(x1),id(x2),id(x3)
Out[74]: (140146931335720, 140146931335504, 140146931335600, 140146931335576)
In [75]: type(x0)
Out[75]: numpy.int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Looks like numpy creates np.array in such way, concate( np.int64([all odd index]), np.int64([all even indices])). I checked with a larger array, I found that all odd and all even indices have the same object id.

Comment: That alternation is, I think, just an artifact of asking for values one after the other without hanging to any of them.   It's just a memory reuse step, done by python, not `numpy`.  In my earlier answer it took pains to avoid this reuse of ids:  `x, y = arr[10], arr[10]; id(x), id(y)`.